# HTTP range requests are not cached by Firefox nor Chrome

Tags: browser-cache, range-requests

This range request seems to never be cached neither by Firefox 102.0.1 nor Chrome 103.0.5060.53:

```js
await fetch("https://sentinel-cogs.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/sentinel-s2-l2a-cogs/2020/S2A_36QWD_20200701_0_L2A/TCI.tif", {
    "credentials": "omit",
    "headers": {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:102.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/102.0",
        "Accept": "*/*",
        "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
        "Range": "bytes=0-5",
        "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
        "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
        "Sec-Fetch-Site": "cross-site"
    },
    "referrer": "http://localhost:8080/",
    "method": "GET",
    "mode": "cors"
});
```

Returns (in Firefox):

```
HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
x-amz-id-2: jGkETlSznrL2heZz48jtyNuZelyqgCBJFDGgGMlzkWeQ3Eyha16y8bs1A4kJbcyXCOpPtmGmFis=
x-amz-request-id: B0NZTXZGYV6D6YPT
Date: Tue, 12 Jul 2022 09:49:45 GMT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: HEAD, GET
Vary: Origin, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Method
Last-Modified: Wed, 01 Jul 2020 15:33:02 GMT
ETag: "1cfd50c6d5047f6e76a2c8b848e2866c-28"
Cache-Control: public, max-age=31536000, immutable
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Range: bytes 0-5/234841786
Content-Type: image/tiff; application=geotiff; profile=cloud-optimized
Server: AmazonS3
Content-Length: 6
```

Is there something wrong with the request ?

Comment: I'm dealing with the same issue. I've setup this demo, where the caching does work for range-header requests https://jsfiddle.net/3vjstogr/ , but somehow the caching doesn't work in my actual application, with virtually identical conditions. So far I wasn't able to gain insight into Chrome's logic for deciding what to cache. PS. the jsfiddle won't work on firefox due to different CORS handling.